# Kinesis Analytics SQL: Throtte only 1 row every N minutes

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am writing a SQL that outputs a row when there is a specific condition. This is connected to a stream and then a Lambda is called. The problem comes when this condition asserts true several times in a short time of period. I would like to trigger my Lambda only once every N minutes.

My solution read from `DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM` with a sliding window of N minutes and if count(*) == 0 then it sent a new row, but I got an error `Object definition contains recursive cycle`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I misunderstood some concepts about the streaming. If you need to send an event just every N minutes, use something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP_PRE" AS INSERT INTO "PREDESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
SELECT STREAM FID, COUNT(*) OVER SLIDING_WINDOW AS TOTAL
FROM "SQL_STREAM_BOTTLENECK"
WINDOW SLIDING_WINDOW AS (PARTITION BY FID RANGE INTERVAL '60' SECOND PRECEDING);

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "STREAM_PUMP_RESULT" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
SELECT STREAM FID, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM "PREDESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
GROUP BY FID, FLOOR(PREDESTINATION_SQL_STREAM.ROWTIME TO MINUTE);
```

Your data comes from `SQL_STREAM_BOTTLENECK`, then you group by all the events in the last minute, and finally you send an event every 1 minute.